# Qt: construct a mutable iterator for template (maps, lists, sets, ...)

Tags: c++, qt, templates, iterator, c++17

In my code I often have functions doing the same thing on different iterable Qt Container types, for instance:

```
void removeX(QMap<qint64, QString> & map)
{
    QMutableMapIterator<qint64, QString> it(map);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        if (it.value() == "X") it.remove();
    }
}

void removeX(QList<QString> & list)
{
    QMutableListIterator<QString> it(list);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        if (it.value() == "X") it.remove();
    }
}
```

(and I know there is already a `removeAll` function in QList. This is just a silly minimal example)

The actual code is more complex and hence this introduces a lot of code duplication. I would prefer to have something like:

```
template <typename T>
void removeX_(T & container)
{
    typename T::mutable_iterator it(container);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        if (it.value() == "X") it.remove();
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't compile, as there is simply no "::mutable_iterator" type definition within Qt. Could one construct one? I don't see a easy way to so. A function like "template<...> getMyMutableIterator" can't work in this case, as we are not allowed to return different types for an overloaded function.

But there is a plenty of new "template magic" from C++17 which I have not really understood yet. I could imagine that it could be a easy way to realize the above code. Has anyone a solution to reduce the code duplication here?

Comment: Have you tried `std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), [](auto& x) { return x.value() == "X"});` Both `QMap` and `QList` provide an STL iterator interface.

Comment: I know there is `remove_if` but the actual code is more complex. For instance, the container stays unchanged or is completely cleared if some conditions are met which I want to check in the same function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a traits template, and partially specialise for the appropriate containers

```
template <typename Container> struct q_container_traits;

template <typename T> struct q_container_traits<QList<T>>
{
    using mutable_iterator = QMutableListIterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = QListIterator<T>;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value> struct q_container_traits<QMap<Key, Value>>
{
    using mutable_iterator = QMutableMapIterator<Key, Value>;
    using const_iterator = QMapIterator<Key, Value>;
};

// etc
```

You then use `q_container_traits<T>` in your function.

```
template <typename T>
void removeX(T & container)
{
    typename q_container_traits<T>::mutable_iterator it(container);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        if (it.value() == "X") it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to disable a function template for those parameters `T` that don't have the `mutable_iterator` type using [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t
<
    std::is_same_v
    <
        typename T::mutable_iterator, 
        mutable_iterator
    >, 
    void
> 
removeX_(T & container)
{
    typename T::mutable_iterator it(container);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        if (it.value() == "X") it.remove();
    }
}
```

This reads something like: enable the void type as the return type of the function if `T::mutable_iterator` type is the same as `mutable_iterator`. If T doesn't have `mutable_iterator`, the substitution fails.

You can use `type_traits` to adapt this to other conditions on `T`, or its iterator, like [check if it has the `remove()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't really see how this helps. There is no "::mutable_iterator" in Qt, I just used this as a placeholder - I need some "magic" at this point, which automatically translates this placeholder in the constructor of the matching Iterator (i.e., `QMutableMapIterator`, `QMutableListIterator`, ...)

Comment: Hm, then I didn't understand your question. You are trying to construct the iterator by defining its type with `typename`. Can you construct it as the return from the container member function `begin`? `auto iterator = container.begin();`? What are the conditions on the iterator, to have the `remove()` member function?