# Create alias template for any STL container

Tags: c++

I need to create a template type to work with any container STL that is:

Example:

```
template <typename T>
using STL_container = ...;
```

And use:

```
void PrintVectorOrList(STL_container<int> container) { ... }

void PrintMap(STL_container<std::string, int> container) { ... }
```

How to make alias template?

Comment: `How to do it better?` Better in what way? How do you measure if something is better? Why is simple `using =` not satisfactory? `void PrintVectorOrList(STL_container<int> container)` Why not just `template <typename T> print_any_container(T container) { .. }`? (maybe with a check if `std::enable_if<std::is_same<T::value_type, int> >` or similar)

Comment: better in terms of what? Please explain the meaning of "better"

Comment: Notice that vector has also allocation in addition to value_type...

Comment: Are you looking for C++20 concept? as [ranges' ones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Range_concepts)

Comment: you could use template template parameters, but standard containers have a variety of different template parameters. If you want to write a generic `Print` you should try it with iterators.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you are interested in accessing the iterator types of different containers, this idea might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232760/qt-construct-a-mutable-iterator-for-template-maps-lists-sets

Comment: Alias templates won't help you here. They just create new names for types.

Comment: What does "to work with any container STL" mean to you? What is `STL_container<int>`? I see that it's a parameter to a non-template function, so it must be some concrete type. Can you provide more detail what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want template functions:

```
template <typename Container, typename ValueType>
constexpr bool IsContainerOf = std::is_same_v<ValueType, typename Container::value_type>;
// Possibly extra check has begin/end


template <typename Container,
          std::enable_if_t<IsContainerOf<Container, int>, bool> = false>
void PrintVectorOrList(const Container& container)
{
    for (int i : container) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename Container,
          std::enable_if_t<IsContainerOf<Container, std::pair<std::string, int>>, bool> = false>
void PrintMap(const Container& container)
{
    for (const auto& [s, i] : container) {
        std::cout << s << ": " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

C++20 would allow concepts instead of SFINAE to have syntax similar to

```
void PrintListOrVector(const Container<int> auto& container) {/*..*/}
void PrintMap(const Container<std::pair<std::string, int>> auto& container) {/*..*/}
```